# Why are kinetic energy equations of simple pendulum and physical pendulum different?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics

Before you continue, please excuse my English. It is not my native language.
I have recently started learning classical dynamics by myself.
I was wondering why kinematic energy equations for simple pendulum and physical pendulum so different?
I am aware that for a simple pendulum, $$KE_{simple} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
and for a physical pendulum, $$KE_{physical} = \frac{1}{2}I{\omega}^2\text{ (edited to use moment of inertia})$$where $m$ is mass, $I$ is the mass moment of inertia, and $v, \omega$ are linear and angular velocity respectively.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second equation does not make sense. It is not even an energy.

Comment: Your second equation is essentially incorrect - it doesn't even make sense from a dimensional-analysis standpoint - as the role of the mass should be taken up by a moment of inertia. Where did you get it from?

Comment: The 2nd equation $(K=\frac12 I\omega^2)$ applies to both situations. For the simple pendulum $I=mr^2$ and $v=r\omega$, giving the 1st equation. However, the latter equations do not apply generally.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is right? I would say that

$KE_{phys}=\frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 $

Where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the rigid body. In fact, it's like that because a physical pendulum is a pendulum made of a rigid body.

Comment: Okay, so I guess your question is why the kinetic energy of a rigid body is $I\omega^2/2$.  Well, just check that $I$ is defined as $mr^2$ and so $I\omega^2=mr^2\omega^2=m(r\omega)^2=mv^2$ because it describes a circular motion.